# Integrating zoom in/out keyboard shortcuts using CMD +/- keys in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I’m unable to integrate my own zoom in/out keyboard shortcuts in a SwiftUI `CommandMenu`. Per Apple’s docs I can see that [CMD +/- shortcuts are “reserved”](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/inputs/keyboards/#specifications).

Is there any way I can bind custom actions from CMD +/- similar to Safari or Maps? I’m using SwiftUI and hoping to find a solution that works on both iOS and Catalyst.